# How to save multiple screenshots in loop with selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium

The code finds a search bar on the page, inputs links and saves screenshots in a loop for each result for each link. What is the right way to make the screenshots to be saved under different names in the folder? For now, they are not saved at all.

```
for i in listOfLinks:
    searchBar = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="syte-react"]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/form/input')
    searchBar.click()
    insertLink = searchBar.send_keys(i)
    clickSubmit = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//*[@id="syte-react"]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/form/button').click()
    results = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="imajs-overlay--"]')
    time.sleep(5)
    filename = i.split('//')[-1] + '.png'
    browser.get_screenshot_as_file('C:\\Users\\Valeriia\\PycharmProjects\\selen\\tests_results\\apr_network'+ filename)
    print('ok')
    browser.refresh()
    time.sleep(5)
    continue
print("the end")
browser.close()
```

Comment: I always add the datetime stamp at the end of a file name to keep them separate.  Also helps to remember when it was taken when uploaded to tickets.  This will always be unique (I use year, month (2 digit number), day, hour(24 hour format), minute and second).  Potentially sorts better this way, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below I am mentioning 3 approach, first  one is yours, working fine for me.

Please do modification as per your requirement.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import datetime
opt=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
opt.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driver= webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chrome driver\\chromedriver.exe",options=opt)
driver.get("http://xfas.in/")

# put below lines in loop
timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M_%S')
driver.get_screenshot_as_file(timestamp+'.png')
print('ok')


# Approch 2
# if your screen is visible you can use pyautogui
import pyautogui
import datetime

timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M_%S')
pyautogui.screenshot(r"c:anypath\timestamp .png")


# Approach 3 long but better
# Even if screen is not visible save the visible page as pdf, best approch as save entire page.


from selenium import webdriver
import shutil
import time
import glob
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import json
import datetime
import os


appState = {
    "recentDestinations": [
        {
            "id": "Save as PDF",
            "origin": "local",
            "account": ""
        }
    ],
    "selectedDestinationId": "Save as PDF",
    "version": 2
}

profile = {'printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState': json.dumps(appState)}

opt=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
opt.add_experimental_option('prefs', profile)
opt.add_argument('--kiosk-printing')
opt.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driver= webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chrome driver\\chromedriver.exe",options=opt)
driver.get("http://xfas.in/")
WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable,((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="txtTracking"]')))

# place these line post the code when you want to save the page.
time.sleep(1)
driver.execute_script('window.print();')
time.sleep(3)

# file will be saved in chrome download folder , in the end partial name of the file and extension
list_of_files = glob.glob(r'C:\Users\path\Downloads\Xfas*.pdf')
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
# copy the path to desired folder
timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M_%S')
shutil.copy(latest_file,'C:\\YourFolder\\Folder2\\'+timestamp+'.pdf')
# one file is copied delete the file from download the folder , choice
os.remove(latest_file)
```